# Runtime error with file io and vectors (C++)

Tags: c++, file-io, vector, runtime-error

Getting a runtime error that says "terminate called after throwing instance of `std::bad_alloc`. "Not sure whats up with it, I'm fairly new to C++.

```
    do
    {
        getline(in_stream, tempstr1);
        itemNumb.push_back(tempstr1);
        getline(in_stream, tempstr2);
        itemNumb.push_back(tempstr2);
        in_stream >> tempdoub;
        itemCost.push_back(tempdoub);
        in_stream >> tempint;
        itemQuant.push_back(tempint);
        index++;
    } while (! in_stream.eof());
    in_stream.close();
```

**Edit:** Should've clarified, `itemNumb` and `itemName` are string vectors, `itemCost` is a double vector, and `itemQuant` is an integer vector. `tempstr1` and 2 are strings, `tempdoub` is a double, and `tempint` is an integer.

Comment: what type is tempstr1-2? Does it say anything else?

Comment: strings are too long...

Answer (score 0):

The loop is potentially infinite if any input operation fails and it is not caused by end of file being reached, which will eventually lead to memory exhaustion.

For example:

```
in_stream >> tempdoub;
```

is probably reading into a `double`. If that fails, the stream will be placed into a bad state (`failbit` is set) and subsequent reads will have no effect and end of file will never be reached. Check the result of input operations immediately:

```
while (getline(in_stream, tempstr1)
       && getline(in_stream, tempstr2)
       && in_stream >> tempdoub
       && in_stream >> tempint)
{
    itemNumb.push_back(tempstr1);   
    itemNumb.push_back(tempstr2);
    itemCost.push_back(tempdoub);
    itemQuant.push_back(tempint);
    index++;
}
```

Comment: I modified it in that way, it is now failing to do anything, so i'm sure the in_stream >> tempdoub and in_stream >> tempint are failing. Any way i can fix that?